# Fill width of Navigation Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a storyboard in which I have a `Navigation Item`, in it I put a `view` with a red background everything works well except when I rotate the device, the `view` inside `Navigation Item` it's not filling the remaining space and t is not allowing me to put a constraint from `view` to its parent `Navaigation Item`

How can I attach a constraint or keep the same distance in portrait and landscape orientations? 
[image]

Comment: can you add two images of portrait and landscape so show what is happening?

Comment: Of course, I already added, I wish the `view` in red background color keep the trailing and leading space to `NavigationItem` width (the one in black color) in landscape orientation

Comment: are you adding the view and buttons in interface builder or with code? if through code, add the code for adding the buttons.  If through interface builder show the auto layout constraints that you have set on the view and buttons